# What does it usually mean when a Haskell record accessor leads with an underscore?

Tags: haskell

An example from the HaskellNet library:

```
data MailboxInfo = MboxInfo { _mailbox :: MailboxName
                            , _exists :: Integer
                            , _recent :: Integer
                            , _flags :: [Flag]
                            , _permanentFlags :: [Flag]
                            , _isWritable :: Bool
                            , _isFlagWritable :: Bool
                            , _uidNext :: UID
                            , _uidValidity :: UID
                            }
                 deriving (Show, Eq)
```

Does the underscore in the field names mean something, if not to the compiler then at least according to Haskell convention?

Answer (score 27):

By analogy to an underscore representing an irrelevant pattern, e.g. `fst (x, _) = x`, an underscore prefix (on record fields or otherwise) is used to indicate that an identifier should be ignored by anyone reading the code, or perhaps ignored by the compiler for certain kinds of user interaction, even though it was given a name for some reason.

Note that this is not merely a convention, but based on something stated explicitly [in the Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.4):

> Underscore, "_", is treated as a lower-case letter, and can occur wherever a lower-case letter can. However, "_" all by itself is a reserved identifier, used as wild card in patterns. Compilers that offer warnings for unused identifiers are encouraged to suppress such warnings for identifiers beginning with underscore. This allows programmers to use "_foo" for a parameter that they expect to be unused.

One example would be definitions that are intended for use by Template Haskell, which then defines equivalent identifiers without the underscore, as in the common example of generating lenses based on record fields (which I'd guess is what your example is doing). In this case the identifiers are more input to TH than an actual definition; the code produced by TH may or may not actually use the underscore-prefixed identifiers.

Other than the above, though, an underscore prefix doesn't do anything differently from a regular lowercase identifier.

Comment: You can see how GHC treats underscore-prefixed identifiers and warnings here: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/options-sanity.html

Comment: See also that proposal to warn about "unused" identifiers that are used anyway: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4959

Answer (score 12):

Template Haskell code sometimes looks for identifiers beginning with an underscore.

[For instance, underscores are used to automate lens generation.](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-lens-template/2.1.7/doc/html/Data-Lens-Template.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is merely a good programming practice.

Since record fields labels in Haskell are actually top level named functions, they pollute the module namespace. Adding an underscore to the field label means that you are free to define another function with the same name.

Comment: There are occasions when you want to actually use that very function, in which case an underscore would be unusual. This is often the case with newtypes, e.g. `newtype Reader e a = Reader { runReader :: e -> a }`

Answer (score 3):

Recently I discovered something relevant to your question.

I wanted to control where the instances of my type are constructed, to prove that every value is valid. So I declared it in its own module:

```
module Coords (Coords(), -- hide the constructor
               x,y,buildCoords) where

data Coords = Coords { x :: Int, y :: Int }

buildCoords :: Int -> Int -> Coords
buildCoords x y | x < 0 || y < 0 = error "omg"
buildCoords x y = Coords { x = x, y = y }
```

Then, I reasoned, from outside this module, no code could create an invalid Coords.

I was wrong! `x` and `y` are public, so one just has to use `let c = buildCoords 1 1 in c { x = -1 }` to get an invalid Coords value!

But this syntax is only possible because x and y are the record selectors of the type. The way to only permit valid values is as follow:

```
module Coords (Coords(), -- hide the constructor
               x,y,buildCoords) where

data Coords = Coords { _x :: Int, _y :: Int }
x = _x
y = _y

buildCoords :: Int -> Int -> Coords
buildCoords x y | x < 0 || y < 0 = error "omg"
buildCoords x y = Coords { _x = x, _y = y }
```

Now x and y are just regular functions. The `c { x = -1 }` syntax won't compile, and other modules do not have access to the record selector _x.

The problem was solved by underscores ;-)

Comment: But you should have used `x_` and `y_` or similar in order to not pretend that the record selectors are unused.